# I can't import `java.time` package

Tags: java, netbeans, time, package, java-time

I want to develop a time slot where there are small time periods in that main time slot. I can't import [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package and it says that package does not exist.

I have jdk1.8.0_111 and from [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) -> Tools -> Java Platforms, I have added. I still can't import the package correctly. Please help me to import this package and continue.

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to import these ... import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.Temporal;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnitl;

Comment: Are you sure you are building your project with jdk8? Can you print-screen the jre view in your IDE?

Comment: I did screenshot. How can i upload it ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Screenshot added !

Comment: The screenshot shows you have JDK8 as platform configured. But it is configured also in your project properties ?

Comment: @SankalpaWijewickrama JDK7 is selected as default - what build system do you use? Maven?

Comment: Ya that was the issue ! Finally after right click and getting the properties of the project i could change the JDK7 into JDK8. Then it is possible to import time package and it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Java 8 and later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8)

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes are built into Java 8 and later. Be sure to:

- Install Java 8 or later
- Configure your IDE to use Java 8 or later
- Configure your build process to use Java 8 or later.

Note that Java 9 fixes a few bugs and adds a few enhancements to the java.time classes over that of Java 8. So when Java 9 ships, revisit all three of those bullets above.

## [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Add this library to your project.

## [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) specifically.

See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).